# Which DRAC 5 P/N is needed/better for a PowerEdge 1950 III?

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac

From my own research, I've seen two different P/Ns for DRAC5 cards.
The two P/Ns I've seen are 0WW126/G8593. What is the difference and which would be best to use with my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These 2 are equivalents in HW.

But there is functional difference in them because "0WW126" comes with express license and has limited functionality and 0G8593 comes with enterprise license which has some extended functionality (as far as I remember some Enhanced Security features, expanded drivers for more supported OS, e.t.c.).

You can use either one for your PowerEdge. They are both completely interchangeable, you will just get less with "0WW126". But again 0G8593 always costs almost double.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and get the 0G8593 version from the seller.